# What is the abbreviation of JAVA language?

Tags: java

Any one know, What is the abbreviation of JAVA language?

Comment: wasn't wikipedia working?

Comment: Why, isn't 4 letters short enough?

Comment: I think the OP means what does Java stand for, as they believe it is an acronym.

Comment: I'm upping this question, if only because of the excellent answer from Bart.

Answer (score 48):

> From: James Gosling 
>   Date: August 24, 2007 8:16:58 PM PDT 
>   To: Jonathan Schwartz 
>   Subject: How was Java named? 
>   
>   The story goes like this:
>
> We needed a name. We had been using
>   "oak" (which was selected essentially
>   randomly by me), and while the team
>   had grown attached to it, the
>   trademark lawyers ruled it out. We had
>   lots of email debates about names, but
>   nothing got resolved. We ended up in
>   the awkward position where the #1
>   thing stopping us from shipping was
>   the name.
>
> Our marketing lead knew someone who
>   was a "naming consultant" (I don't
>   remember his name, but he was great).
>   We could neither afford the price nor
>   the time of a conventional product
>   naming process. He agreed to do
>   something rather odd, but effective
>   and quick: he acted as a facilitator
>   at a meeting where about a dozen of us
>   locked ourselves in a room for an
>   afternoon. He started asking us
>   questions like "How does this thing
>   make you feel?" (Excited!) "What else
>   makes you feel that way?" (Java!) We
>   ended up with a board covered with
>   essentially random words. Then he put
>   us through a sorting process where we
>   ended up with a ranking of the names.
>   We ended up with a dozen name
>   candidates and sent them off to the
>   lawyers: they worked down the list
>   until they hit one that cleared their
>   search. "Java" was the fourth name on
>   the list. The first name on the list
>   was "Silk", which I hated but everyone
>   else liked. My favorite was "Lyric",
>   the third one on the list, but it
>   didn't pass the lawyers test. I don't
>   remember what the other candidate
>   names where.
>
> So, who named Java? Marketing
>   organized the meeting, the consultant
>   ran it, and a whole pile of us did a
>   lot of yelling out of random words.
>   I'm honestly not real sure who said
>   "Java" first, but I'm pretty sure it
>   was Mark Opperman.
>
> There certainly wasn't any brilliant
>   marketing mind who went through a
>   coherent thought process.

-- http://blogs.oracle.com/jonathan/entry/better_is_always_different ([wayback machine mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20090201061721/http://blogs.sun.com/jonathan/entry/better_is_always_different))

Comment: That's a great story, thanks for the citation and sharing!

Comment: Isn't it an episode of Dilbert?

Comment: To add a detail that is not obvious to non native speakers: 'Java' is a colloquial expression meaning 'coffee' (which I guess grows on Java, the island).

Comment: I think its even non obvious for non americans, I'm english and had never heard this name for coffee

Answer (score 12):

Java (not JAVA) isn't an [acronym](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acronym), it's just a name.

Answer (score 3):

It's *not* an abbreviation.  This is a common misconception.  It was [chosen](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonathan/entry/better_is_always_different) at a naming meeting almost at random.

Comment: I believe the original name was going to be C+++, but I can't remember at all where I read that.

Comment: No, the original name was Oak.

Comment: @rpflo: Maybe you are thinking of C#? Word is that the original name of C# was "(C++)-C".

Answer (score 2):

Java isn't an acronym.  It's simply a name.