# Why is Java often spelled as JAVA (usually in old texts)?

Tags: java

Do you know any reason for spelling the name of the Java programming language uppercase? I see this very often in (especially old) articles and this ugly spelling made me curious.  I think as it is not an acronym it shouldn't be uppercase.

Just an example:

> CORBA 2.2 (February 1998) - This version of CORBA includes the Server
>   Portability enhancements (POA), DCOM Interworking, and the IDL/JAVA
>   language mapping specification.
>
> Source: http://www.omg.org/gettingstarted/history_of_corba.htm

Does it have any historical reason?

Comment: You're right, it's wrong (and I find it's most common with beginners and people who don't know much about Java - go figure). I'm not sure if it's off-topic, but I can't make a convincing argument that it's on topic either. Maybe Programmers.SE? Wouldn't be the first terminology question.

Comment: Previous discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042854/what-is-the-abbreviation-of-java-language

Looks like it was always supposed to be "Java".

Comment: For the same reason that people wonder why their string comparison using `==` keeps returning false when the two strings are equal. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no reason.

Java was originally (before general release) called Oak, but Oak was already a trademarked name.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history