# Configuration OCR JAVA Asprise

Tags: java, ocr

I'm starting to Asprise Java technology.
I would like to use a method that converts an image to a text (OCR).

```
import com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\HEAD2.png"));
        String s = new OCR().recognizeEverything(image);

        // prints the results.
         System.out.println("RESULTS: \n"+ s);
}
}
```

but I find these errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\WINDOWS\system32\AspriseOCR.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:247)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.<init>(OCR.java:56)
```

I download the file Asprise OCR-Java-4.0 Windows_XP_32bit

I add the aspriseOCR.jar file in my eclipse project librairy

I also add AspriseOCR.dll file as C:. \ WINDOWS \ system32 but nothing happens .. thank you to help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix an UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries) in a JNI project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092200/how-to-fix-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-find-dependent-libraries-in-a-jni-pro)

Comment: I have add those to dll to C:\Windiows\System32\ 

Copy 
- AspriseOCR.dll
- DevIL.dll
- ILU.dll 

and it is working fine Now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042854/what-is-the-abbreviation-of-java-language

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using version 4.

To fix your error:

1. Download the newer version (version 5) of Asprise [OCR SDK Library API for Java](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-api-overview.html)
2. Add the single jar file aocr.jar to your classpath.

That's it.

I've upgraded your code in your post to this new version:

```
import com.asprise.ocr.Ocr
...
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
    Ocr.setUp(); // one time setup
    Ocr ocr = new Ocr(); // create a new OCR engine
    ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST); // English
    String s = ocr.recognize(new File[] {new File("D:\\HEAD2.png")},
      Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
    System.out.println("Result: " + s);
    ocr.stopEngine();
  }
}
```

There is no dependency DLL in this new version.

Comment: I'm tempted to remove the "Notes" section since one could simply read that from the README or go to the main site and take a look at the new features.