# Private field name being confused with private string name in Java

Tags: java, android

In an app that I am building I am retrieving the value of a field title "private" and I need to return it for use within the app. As you can probably see, the title of the field is giving me problems inside the JAVA because the field is being confused.

What would be the best way to fix this? Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

JSON

```
"private": true,
```

Java

```
private String private;

public String getPrivate() {
    return private;
}
```

---

**Update**

I do not have access to edit the page that is returning the JSON. Changing the value in the JSON is the obvious option, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get around that somehow with JAVA.

---

**Note**

Thanks for the suggestions everyone! I appreciate it.

Comment: Change the variable name (where the JSON is comming from).

Comment: That will never work private is a reserved keyword in Java.

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki I know it will never work. That is why I asked for suggestions. Do you have any?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042854/what-is-the-abbreviation-of-java-language

Comment: There is no 'getting around.' Are you manually deserializing the JSON, or using a library such as Jackson? Most libraries have ways to manage how fields are mapped.

Comment: @TomG That's what I was afraid of hearing.

Answer (score 6):

private is a keyword in java and you cannot use them for variable names as they are reserved. You need to rename your variable to some other name. As the javadoc says:

> You cannot use any of the keyword as identifiers in your programs.

Here is the javadoc reference for complete list of keywords:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the problem is caused by the fact that `private` is a keyword in Java.

You have three options:

- Change your JSON so that you don't use `private` (or any other Java keyword) as a JSON attribute name.
- Tweak the JSON binding you are using so that it maps the offending attribute name to a legal Java identifier.

  For example, if you are using JSON Jackson databindings, then the simple way to do this is to write the Java class with a getter/setter for a field with a different name (say `proivit`) and then add a `@JsonProperty("private")` annotation to the `getProivit` method.
- If you are writing the Java classes by hand, you can use whatever (legal) name you want for the private variable.  So just write the code like this:

  ```
      private String proivit;

      public String getPrivate() {
          return proivit;
      }
  ```

Comment: Your third option is a good one, but it returns null. I need it to return the value of the private JSON field.

Comment: What binding are you using?  It must be injecting the `proivit` variable directly rather than using the setter.  (Or did you leave out the setter?)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is change the variable name to isPrivate

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you're using to convert between JSON and Java, but it appears to be based on the JavaBeans naming convention. If that's true, then your variable need have no relation to the name of the methods used to access it:

```
private String fubar;

public String getPrivate() {
    return this.fubar;
}

public void setPrivate(String value) {
    this.fubar = value;
}
```

If you're using an IDE to generate getters and setters, you'll have to manually edit the method names. You'll probably also want to edit the argument name for consistency.

If you're using a framework that ignores getters/setters and accesses the variable directly, then you don't have many options. A `String.replace()` will work, but it will also damage JSON like

```
{ `"foo": "this is private: do not publish"` }
```