# How Convert String to Json with ok&[{"e... (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have this string:

```
ok&[{"extension":".pdf","nombreArchivo":"BL.12345.pdf","nroOrdenCompra":"11552","nroEmbarque":"11552-6","idEmbarque":13344,"idArchivo":1521},{"extension":".png","nombreArchivo":"Selecci\u00f3n_089.png","nroOrdenCompra":"12065","nroEmbarque":"745754754-1,12067-1,11553-4,PRUEBA03-2,12009-1,12065-5,PRUEBA01-2","idEmbarque":9725,"idArchivo":1484}]&
```

then I tried convert to json with JSON.parse

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(response.data);
console.log(myobj);
```

I get an error with the position.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's invalid JSON.  It looks like a javascript array with `ok&` at the beginning.  If that `ok&` wasn't there it might work.  PS you are converting *from* JSON with `.parse`, not *to*

Comment: And the `&` at the end needs to go as well.

Comment: Back Side with JAVA: 
`JSONArray array = new JSONArray();        
        for (ResultadoQueryArchivo resultadoQueryArchivo : listaArchivo) {            
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("idArchivo", resultadoQueryArchivo.getIdArchivo());
            obj.put("idOrdenCompra",
            obj.put("nroEmbarque", resultadoQueryArchivo.getNroEmbarque());
            obj.put("extension", resultadoQueryArchivo.getExtension());
            array.put(obj);
        }
        setAjaxResponse(array.toString());`

Comment: Java, not JAVA. [Java is not an acronym.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042879/179125)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data.match(/\[(.*)\]/)[0]));
console.log(myobj);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your console told you:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0
```

At the first position your `o` is wrong. Valid json-structur is:

```
{ "key": "value" }
[{ "key": "value" }]
[ "key","key" ]
```

Here you can find more specific information. [json syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp)

Therefor you need to remove the `ok&` and `?` from you string.

```
var json = string.slice(3, -1);
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

There you go.